# How can I get the content of 2 columns and show this?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

```
    public void ShowFirstFiveHighScore()
    {
        string query = "SELECT 'key', 'PlayerName', 'HighScore' FROM PlayerPoints ORDER BY HighScore DESC LIMIT 5";

        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
               MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(...);
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

I try to show the columns "PlayerName" and "HighScore". Maybe in a MessageBox? Any Help? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use `'` with column names when you call them in a `SELECT` part.

Comment: Why do you call `ExecuteNonQuery` before closing connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use single quotes (`'`) with column names when you call them in a `SELECT` part in your query. You need to use it with character values.

Second of all, [`MySqlDataReader.GetString` method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader-getstring) takes `int` as a parameter which is *zero-based* column number. That means you can specify your columns with `1` and `2` and show them as you want.

`KEY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. You need to quote it with `` ` ``  character. **However**, the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.

Your [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery) is meaningless with `SELECT` statement. It doesn't do *anything* at all.

You need to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` (also `MySqlConnection` when you write).

```
string query = "SELECT `key`, PlayerName, HighScore FROM PlayerPoints ORDER BY HighScore DESC LIMIT 5";
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection))
using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
      while (reader.Read())
      {
           MessageBox.Show(string.Format("PlayerName: {0} HighScore: {1}",
                                          reader.GetString(1),
                                          reader.GetString(2)));
      }
}
```

> Thank @Soner. It works. How can I show all five results in a
>   MessageBox? not in five different MessageBoxes?

Then you can concatenate your `5` rows in one string inside your *while statement* and show it outside of *while statement*. Like;

```
string s = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    s += string.Format("PlayerName: {0} HighScore: {1}\n",
                        reader.GetString(1),
                        reader.GetString(2)));
}
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Comment: @Ramo Are you sure your select statement returns values? Please debug your code and see.

Comment: Thank @Soner. It works. How can I show all five results in a MessageBox? not in five different MessageBoxes?

Comment: @Ramo Then you can concatenate your `5` rows as a one string and show it after your _while statement_. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ShowFirstFiveHighScore()
{
    string query = "SELECT 'key', PlayerName, HighScore FROM PlayerPoints ORDER BY HighScore DESC LIMIT 5";

    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
           MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}-{1}"),reader.GetString(1),
                                      reader.GetString(2));
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work OK. Alternatively, Concatenate the columns of interest as required in the Query and display the concatenated value.